# Xerox WorkCentre 3045 not printing

Tags: 12.10, printing

My brother bought a Xerox WorkCentre 3045 printer, but even after intalling the drivers I can't get it to work. It is a wireless printer, and is detected when going to printers, installing it works, but it just won't print. I haven't tried connecting it with Usb.

Printing a test page from the setup wizard makes the printer state "Idle - Processing page 1..."

Going to "http://localhost:631/" (cups) shows the printer there, but the job state is 'stopped "Filter failed"'.

The cups page says the printer is connected on socket://10.0.0.65:9100

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I solved my issue with Phaser 6010N with original drivers and 32bit libs, which are absent in Ubuntu 13 and later by default. Just leave it here:
https://forum.support.xerox.com/t5/Printing/Phaser-6010-driver-Linux-64-bits/m-p/253197/highlight/true#M27951

Answer (score 1):

Did you install drivers from Xerox site or those suggested by Ubuntu? You could also try to connect it via the second option (DNS-SD or whatever the name is). At least this is what is working for me